# merging and extracting lists

Tags: lisp, scheme

I'm writing a function that merges two lists. If one of the list's item is a list, I need to extract it too.

```
list1:'(1 (2 3 4) 5 6)) 

list2: '(7 (8 9) 10 (11))

output: (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11)
```

I tried to solve it by my code doesn't work.  What is the problem?

```
(define (merge lis1 lis2)
    (define (combine lis fine)
        (cond
            ((null? lis) lis)
            ((list? lis) (combine (car lis) fine) (combine (cdr lis) fine))
            (else  (cons lis fine))))

        (cond
            (combine (cons lis2 lis1) '())))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply use the library function `flatten`.

```
(define (merge lis1 lis2)
  (flatten (cons lis1 lis2)))
```

`flatten` takes a list that can contain lists (who in turn can contain more lists, ...) and flattens the result into a list of non-lists, which is what your combine function seems to be trying to do.

`(flatten '(1 2 (3 (4 5) 6)))` returns `'(1 2 3 4 5 6)`

If this library function is off limits, your code is actually pretty close to correct.

The first issue is on the `((list? lis) (combine (car lis) fine) (combine (cdr lis) fine)  )` line.  `fine` is never changed, so the code evaluates `(combine (car lis) fine)` and then returns `(combine (cdr lis) fine)`, where the `fine` in the second expression is the original value of `fine`.  This line is the same thing as `((list? lis) (combine (cdr lis) fine)  )`, which is obviously not what we want.  Instead, we have to use the first expression inside the second expression `((list? lis) (combine (cdr lis) (combine (car lis) fine)))`.

The second issue is that, in combine, when `lis` is null, we need to return `fine`, not `lis`.

The next issue is that this code goes through the list, takes the first element of `lis` and puts it on the front of `fine`, and then passes the newly created list and uses it for the next iteration of the function, where it takes second value in `lis` and sticks it on the front of the new `fine`, in front of the first value of `lis`.  The results in the order of the return value of `fine` being reversed -- `(merge '(1 2 (3)) '(4 (5 6)))` will return `(6 5 4 3 2 1)`.  We have two choices: we can call reverse on the return from `combine` in the body of `merge` or we can invert the line we changed above, making it `((list? lis) (combine (car lis) (combine (cdr lis) fine)))`.  This means that we would add the rest of the list to `fine` before adding the current element, which is what we want.

Another issue is that we need to cons `lis1` to `lis2`, not the other way around.

The final issue is that the `cond` in the body of `merge` is unnecessary -- we can remove it.

As a side note, it is generally considered neater to not give close parentheses a new line and indent the body of a `define` or `cond` by just two spaces.

With all of these changes, the final code is:

```
(define (merge lis1 lis2)
  (define (combine lis fine)
    (cond
      ((null? lis) fine)
      ((list? lis) (combine (car lis)
                            (combine (cdr lis) fine)))
      (else  (cons lis fine))))

  (combine (cons lis1 lis2) '()))
```